# Not sure what derivative to take

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a relation $$\frac{(x\cos(\tan^{-1}(x_1))-y\sin(\tan^{-1}(x_1)))^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y\cos(\tan^{-1}(x_1))+x\sin(\tan^{-1}(x_1)))^2}{b^2}=1$$

$a^2$ and $b^2$ are both functions solely in terms of $x_1$. For various real number values of $x_1$, the function on the Cartesian coordinate plane is that of a rotated ellipse. I want to find what the equation of the derivative of that ellipse trends towards as $x_1$ approaches toward infinity. I believe to get that I need the limit as $x_1$ approaches infinity of some sort of function in both $x_1$ and $x$ in which I can substitute $x_1$ and get the equation of the derivative of the  ellipse that is formed by that value of $x_1$. 
I presume to get that I need to take some type of derivative, however, I do not know what type that might be, or whether it is even possible to get the derivatives of the ellipses simply by substituting a variable.

Comment: The parentheses are unbalanced in the second term. I suspect that the term should be $\frac{(y\cos(\tan^{-1}(x_1))+x\sin(\tan^{-1}(x_1)))^2}{b^2}$, but I can't be certain.

Comment: That’s right, thank you for changing that!

Comment: What do you mean by "the derivative of an ellipse?"  Do you mean the derivative of $y$ as an implicit function of $x$?  What is the derivative of $x^2+y^2=1?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's important to clear up some terminology, since it really informs the approach here. The equation

$$\frac{[x\cos(\tan^{-1}s)-y\sin(\tan^{-1}s)]^2}{a(s)^2}+\frac{[y\cos(\tan^{-1}s)+x\sin(\tan^{-1}s)]^2}{b(s)^2}=1, \text{ for } s\in\mathbb{R}$$

is *not* a function. If you attempt to solve for either of the variables to write it as a function, you will find that you will be unable to fully describe the all the points as the graph of a function of either $x$ or $y$. Graphically, this is equivalent to the fact that there is at least 1 vertical and 1 horizontal line which intersects any ellipse.

The ellipse is a closed, non-self-intersecting, planar curve, and in general there are 2 ways to get the derivative. The first is by calculating the derivative directly via implicit differentiation, and the second is by parameterizing the curve as a function of 1 variable and taking the derivative of that function. These two derivatives $y'(x,y)$ and $F'(\theta) = (F'(\theta)_x,F'(\theta)_y)$ will be different, but are related by $y'(F(\theta)) = \frac{F'(\theta)_y}{F'(\theta)_x}$, where $F(\theta) = (x,y)$ is the parameterization.

---

Let's try implicit differentiation. Before going ahead, let's make the substitution $c(s) = \cos(\tan^{-1}s)$ and $d(s) = \sin(\tan^{-1}s)$, and for simplicity we may drop the explicit $s$ dependence when referencing $a,b,c,d$. With this, the equation becomes

$$ \frac{(cx-dy)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(dx+cy)^2}{b^2}=1 $$

We take the derivative of both sides with respect to $x$, considering $y$ as a (possibly multi-valued) function of $x$. Thus, $\frac{\text d}{\text dx} f(y) = f'(y)y'$ for any differentiable function $f$. This gives us the equation

$$ \frac{(cx-dy)(c-dy')}{a^2} + \frac{(dx+cy)(d+cy')}{b^2} = 0 $$

which can be solved for $y'$ to give

$$ y'(x,y) = \frac{b^2c(cx-dy)+a^2d(dx+cy)}{b^2d(cx-dy)-a^2c(dx+cy)} $$

As $s\to\pm\infty$, $c\to 0$ and $d\to \pm 1$. Thus, we can write the limit

$$ \lim\limits_{s\to\pm\infty} y'(x,y;s) = -\frac{a(\pm\infty)^2}{b(\pm\infty)^2}\frac{x}{y}$$

This gives an expression for the derivative in terms of points $(x,y)$ on the ellipse. You need to be careful with this, though, because it will also give you a value for points *off* the ellipse, which are not meaningful. If you want an equation which only relates points on the ellipse to their derivative, you can solve the original ellipse equation for $y$, splitting into two functions for the upper and lower halves, and substituting each of those for $y$ to get the two corresponding expressions for the derivatives. I'll leave this to you if you want to do it.

---

Alternatively, you can write the curve as the graph of  a function of 1 variable. Before doing this, we will make the substitution $\tan^{-1}s = \phi$, and so define the functions $A(\phi) = a(\tan\phi)$ and $B(\phi) = b(\tan\phi)$, and for simplicity we may drop the explicit $\phi$ dependence when referencing $A,B$. Then, define the function

$$F(\theta) = (A\cos\theta\cos\phi + B\sin\theta\sin\phi, - A\cos\theta\sin\phi + B\sin\theta\cos\phi)$$

We can take the derivative easily

$$F'(\theta) = (-A\sin\theta\cos\phi + B\cos\theta\sin\phi, A\sin\theta\sin\phi + B\cos\theta\cos\phi)$$

Then we can write the derivative as a function of $\theta$ by dividing

$$y'(F(\theta)) = \frac{B\cos\theta\cos\phi+A\sin\theta\sin\phi }{ B\cos\theta\sin\phi-A\sin\theta\cos\phi }$$

As $s\to\pm\infty$, $\phi\to\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, so we can write the limit

$$\lim\limits_{\phi\to\pm\frac{\pi}{2}} y'(F(\theta);\phi) = \frac{A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})}{ B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})}\tan\theta $$

---

Equivalence of these two expressions can be seen as follows. When $\phi\to\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$, $F(\theta)\to(\pm B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta),\mp A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(\theta))$. Substituting this into $y'(x,y)$, noting that $a(\pm\infty) = A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $b(\pm\infty) = B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})$, gives the expression

$$y'(F(\theta)) = -\frac{A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})^2}{B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})^2}\frac{\pm B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})\sin(\theta)}{\mp A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})\cos(\theta)} = \frac{A(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})}{ B(\pm\frac{\pi}{2})}\tan\theta$$